# Why does a Gensim Doc2vec object return empty doctags?

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

My question is **how I should interpret my situation?**

I trained a Doc2Vec model following this tutorial https://blog.griddynamics.com/customer2vec-representation-learning-and-automl-for-customer-analytics-and-personalization/.

For some reason, `doc_model.docvecs.doctags` returns `{}`. But `doc_model.docvecs.vectors_docs` seems to return a proper value.

Why the doc2vec object doesn't return any doctags but vectors_docs?

Thank you for any comments and answers in advance.

This is the code I used to train a Doc2Vec model.

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import LabeledSentence, TaggedDocument, Doc2Vec
import timeit
import gensim

embeddings_dim = 200    # dimensionality of user representation

filename = f'models/customer2vec.{embeddings_dim}d.model'
if TRAIN_USER_MODEL:

    class TaggedDocumentIterator(object):
        def __init__(self, df):
           self.df = df
        def __iter__(self):
            for row in self.df.itertuples():
                yield TaggedDocument(words=dict(row._asdict())['all_orders'].split(),tags=[dict(row._asdict())['user_id']])

    it = TaggedDocumentIterator(combined_orders_by_user_id)

    doc_model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(vector_size=embeddings_dim, 
                                      window=5, 
                                      min_count=10, 
                                      workers=mp.cpu_count()-1,
                                      alpha=0.055, 
                                      min_alpha=0.055,
                                      epochs=20)   # use fixed learning rate

    train_corpus = list(it)

    doc_model.build_vocab(train_corpus)

    for epoch in tqdm(range(10)):
        doc_model.alpha -= 0.005                    # decrease the learning rate
        doc_model.min_alpha = doc_model.alpha       # fix the learning rate, no decay
        doc_model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=doc_model.corpus_count, epochs=doc_model.iter)
        print('Iteration:', epoch)

    doc_model.save(filename)
    print(f'Model saved to [{filename}]')

else:
    doc_model = Doc2Vec.load(filename)
    print(f'Model loaded from [{filename}]')
```

`doc_model.docvecs.vectors_docs` returns[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the `tags` you supply are plain Python ints, those ints are used as the direct-indexes into the vectors-array.

This saves the overhead of maintaining a mapping from arbitrary tags to indexes.

But, it may also cause an over-allocation of the vectors array, to be large enough for the largest int tag you provided, even if other lower ints are never used. (That is: if you provided a single document, with a `tags=[1000000]`, it will allocate an array sufficient for tags 0 to 1000000, even if most of those never appear in your training data.)

If you want `model.docvecs.doctags` to collect a list of all your tags, use string tags rather than plain ints.

Separately: don't call `train()` multiple times in your own loop, or manage the `alpha` learning-rate in your own code, unless you have an overwhelmingly good reason to do so. It's inefficient & error-prone. (Your code, for example, is actually performing 200 training-epochs, and if you were to increase the loop count without carefully adjusting your `alpha` increment, you could wind up with nonsensical negative `alpha` values – a very common error in code following this bad practice. Call `.train()` once with your desired number of epochs. Set the `alpha` and `min_alpha` at reasonable starting and nearly-zero values – probably just the defaults unless you're sure your change is helping – and then leave them alone.

Comment: The `tags` I am supplying are actually strings. What are some other factors that could affect the result other than int vs string tags?

Comment: The only things that would cause `model.docvecs.doctags` to be empty would be (1) using only ints as tags; or (2) not actually providing any tags at all. Double check the `TaggedDocument` instances you're creating. (For example, look at `train_corpus[0].tags`, to be sure it's the sort of tags you intended, and `len(train_corpus)`, to be sure it's the size you intended.)

Comment: Apparently, my `tags` were integers. The `words` I am plugging are strings. Thank you so much for your help. I resolved my problem by converting `tags` into `strings`.